# How do i disable a submit button when checkbox is uncheck?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have something [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8YBu5/) that cannot seem to help me disable the submit button. any ideas?

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="checky"><a href="#">terms and conditions</a>
<input type="submit" id="postme" value="submit">

$('#checky').click(function(){
    if($(this).checked == false){
         $('#postme').attr("disabled","disabled");   
    } else {
        $('#postme').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be checking for the attribute `checked` and not the method.

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8YBu5/7/

```
$('#checky').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('checked') == false){
         $('#postme').attr("disabled","disabled");   
    } else {
        $('#postme').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

Remember that this code needs to be wrapped inside `$(document).ready()` or put at the bottom of your html code, otherwise your JS will bind itself to DOM elements that have not been loaded yet and will fail.

**Wrapping it in .ready()**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checky').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr('checked') == false){
             $('#postme').attr("disabled","disabled");   
        } else {
            $('#postme').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This code can be put anywhere in the document and will only trigger once the DOM is ready so you don't have to worry about premature triggers.

**Putting it at the bottom of your document**

```
<!-- some HTML -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
        $('#checky').click(function(){
            if($(this).attr('checked') == false){
                 $('#postme').attr("disabled","disabled");   
            } else {
                $('#postme').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you're putting it at the bottom of your document, you don't need to wrap it in `.ready()` because the javascript will not be read until everything else has loaded. There is a performance boost in this method (if you have a lot of JS)

You can use either one of these methods to make sure that your JS binds event handling methods to DOM elements only *after* they have finished loading.

Comment: +1 though he wasn't checking for the method, he was checking the property on the collection.

Comment: @john it works perfectly on the jsfiddle, however on my ide the script doesnt even run. i have placed alert test after the click function but it does not even trigger. is there a reason why?

Comment: if you're using firefox, hit CTRL + SHIFT + J and look at the errors tab to check what errors are present. Also make, sure you included jquery and make sure this method is wrapped inside `$(document).ready(function(){})`

Comment: @john it has to be within $(document).ready(function(){}? can't i just put it in the normal <script></script> tag?

Comment: if you do that, then you have to put it at the bottom. Editing my question to show you how

Comment: @john awesome, finally got it to work from your example..thanks

Comment: As of jQuery 1.6, you should use `prop` instead of `attr`, see my answer below. Also golfs better.

Comment: i like your method, but it still have problems with IE7 and IE8 compatibility.
I tried the below code too:

"<!doctype html>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">"

Use this:
http://jsfiddle.net/8YBu5/7/
My default, the user has to check the box to enable the submit button to move forward.

Comment: If you want the default to be unchecked, this does not work.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(!$(this).is(':checked') ...
```

Comment: I'd personally recommend this over the `.attr('checked') == false` method. Much more readable and beautiful.

Answer (score 4):

Before jQuery 1.6 `attr` was OK, after 1.6 you must use `prop`.

```
$('#checky').click(function(){
  $('#postme').prop('checked', !$(this).checked);
})
```

Attributes and properties are different things, but unfortunately jQuery took a long time to differentiate between them.

See also: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr/24595458#24595458)

Answer (score 2):

change `$(this).checked`  to `if($(this).attr('checked') == false){`

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8YBu5/21/) you go.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
$('#checky').click(function(){

    if(this.checked == false){
         $('#postme').attr("disabled","disabled");   
    }
    else {
        $('#postme').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("#postme").attr("disabled","disabled");
                    $("#checky").click(function(){
                        if($("#checky").is(":checked")){
                         $("#postme").removeAttr("disabled");   
                         }
                        else{
                            $("#postme").attr("disabled","disabled");
                            }
                    });
                })
```

Answer (score -1):

Add to the button `#postme` a click event that checks if the check box is checked.  If it is checked, return false, otherwise return true.

```
$('#postme').click( function () {
    if ( !$('#checky').attr('checked') ) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: He wants the button disabled - this still allows the user to click on the button.