# Enable/Disable submit button if checkbox is checked/unchecked?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

How to enable the submit button in my HTML form and disable if checkbox was unchecked?

What is wrong with this code?

```
EnableSubmit = function(val)
{
    var sbmt = document.getElementById("Accept");

    if (val.checked == true)
    {
        sbmt.disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        sbmt.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

The check box

```
<td width="30%">Do you accept Terms of Service agreement?</td>
<td width="10px" style="min-width: 10px"></td>
<td width="70%">
    <input type="checkbox" name="TOS" value="Accept" onClick="EnableSubmit"> I agree to Terms of Service agreement.
</td>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i disable a submit button when checkbox is uncheck?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458531/how-do-i-disable-a-submit-button-when-checkbox-is-uncheck)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change your HTML to this:

```
<td width="30%">Do you accept Terms of Service agreement?</td>
<td width="10px" style="min-width: 10px"></td>
<td width="70%">
    <input type="checkbox" name="TOS" value="Accept" onClick="EnableSubmit(this)"> I agree to Terms of Service agreement.
</td>
```

Reason it's not working: you're not passing your function anything. Actually, because you've not used parentheses with the function name, you've not called the function at all. Passing it `this` in the context of the `onclick` HTML event attribute means you're passing a reference to the element's DOM object, giving you access to its `checked` property.

Comment: Could you re-enter your question to include the rest of the source for the form (the HTML)? And any other JavaScript you might be using?

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the parameters: `onClick="EnableSubmit()"`

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="TOS" value="Accept" onClick="EnableSubmit()"> I agree to Terms of Service agreement.
```

Answer (score 0):

First if condition checks whether toggle is switched to desired side. Condition can be changed according to requirement. 
Last jquery is to make toggle button grey.

```
 if(!$('#togglehk').is(":checked"))
                    {
                        $('#togglehk').click();
                    }
  jQuery('#togglehk').attr("disabled", true);
  jQuery('#togglehk').prop("disabled",true);

  jQuery('#togglehk').next(".slider").css("backgroundcolor","#B3B3B3");
```