# PHP Submit on Select

Tags: php, html, submit

I am trying to not have a submit button, is there any way that the form can submit when the user selects a value?

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']  ?>" >

    <table class="form">

            <select name="category" class="formfield" id="category">
                <option value="-1"> Category </option>
                <?php
                    $sql_contry = "SELECT * FROM category";
                    $rs_c = mysql_query($sql_contry);
                    while ($row_c = mysql_fetch_array($rs_c)) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$row_c['category'].'">'.$row_c['category'].'</option>';  
                    }
                ?>
             </select>

    </table>

</form>
```

Comment: Yeah, by using javascript !

Comment: You'll have to use Javascript to do that.

Comment: Use javascript. A similar example is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021848/enable-disable-submit-button-if-checkbox-is-checked-unchecked

Answer (score 29):

Here an example

```
<form>
    <select name='myfield' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
      <option selected>Milk</option>
      <option>Coffee</option>
      <option>Tea</option>
    </select>
    <noscript><input type="submit" value="Submit"></noscript>
</form>
```

Using noscript tag it allows browsers that are not JavaScript-enabled to still function.

Comment: who the hell uses `noscript` nowdays and why is this relevant here ?

Comment: @Adidi The content inside the <noscript> element will only be displayed if scripts are not supported, or are disabled in the user’s browser.

Comment: ohhhh what do you say ?! I am just saying that in today internet if someone will disable js he could not surf on 90% of the web - the noscript method was relevant to the web 1.0 world...

Comment: I have tried all of the solutions that everyone has posted, and it isn't quite working yet, but I think it is close.  Normally, when I select a value and click the submit button, it displays data on the screen.  With this method, I can tell that it is submitting, but the data is not being displayed on the screen.  Any thoughts?  That is, without going through 500 lines of code? ;)

Comment: Awsome find! Been Googling around for hours.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - use javascript:

Html:

```
<form id="frm">
   <select onchange="onSelectChange();">
          <option>1</option>
           <option>1</option>
   <select>
</form>
```

js:

```
function onSelectChange(){
 document.getElementById('frm').submit();
}
```

Comment: You actually need to make the js function take an argument or something to make it actually useful. You can't add 2 select lists with this :) . +1

Comment: Yeah - just my cents in case OP finds it confusing.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="product.php" method="POST">
<select onchange="this.form.submit();" name="prod">
    <option value="">Select product</option>
    <option value="1">abc</option>
    <option value="2">def</option>
    <option value="3">ghi</option>
    <option value="4">jkl</option>
    <option value="5">mno</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change code as below, I haven't check code so there may be some error like capital/small letter I am not sure like, it's submit() or Submit() and so on..

```
<script language="javascript">
function submitForm(){
    var val = document.myform.category.value;
    if(val!=-1){
        document.myform.submit();
    }
}
</script>
<form method="post" name="myform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']  ?>" >

    <table class="form">

            <select name="category" class="formfield" id="category" onchange="submitForm();">
                <option value="-1"> Category </option>
                <?php
                    $sql_contry = "SELECT * FROM category";
                    $rs_c = mysql_query($sql_contry);
                    while ($row_c = mysql_fetch_array($rs_c)) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$row_c['category'].'">'.$row_c['category'].'</option>';  
                    }
                ?>
             </select>

    </table>

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I copied and pasted the code, and for some reason it does not submit.  I looked for capital / small letter errors but could not find any.  Any thoughts?