# JSF checkbox listener

Tags: jsf

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="deactivate" title="select to deactivate" />
```

I have a checkbox and a button on my JSF page. I want the button to be enabled only if checkbox is checked.

What is the JSF way of doing this with no manual javascript and no listener method on my java class. There should be way of doing it maybe with an expression something like;

```
"panel group rendered=#{}"
```

one button rendered for enabled and one button rendered or disabled.

Comment: Without JavaScript or POST/refresh, you can't.

Comment: @Alexandre Lavoie ok, then what do you suggest?

Comment: there is already something done in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021848/enable-disable-submit-button-if-checkbox-is-checked-unchecked) question, since JSF render HTML it is the same.

Comment: @Spring What you are looking for is possible but you can also do with ajax but atleast you need a listener for this

Comment: Thank you for the bounty. A hint for the future, if you keep the bounty open as long as possible (7 days), you'll in the end easily earn the spent reputation back by getting sympathy upvotes from users stumbling upon your question via the "Featured" list.

Comment: @BalusC ok, as always another helpful tip

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> *What is the JSF way of doing this with no javascript and no listener method on my java class*

This is plain impossible. I gather that you actually meant, "no manually written JavaScript" (and thus you accept JSF-generated JavaScript as used by [`<f:ajax>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html)) and "no manually written listener method" (and thus you accept JSF own magic on the component tree state).

In that case, this should do:

```html
<h:form>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox binding="#{checkbox}">
        <f:ajax render="button" />
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    <h:commandButton id="button" value="submit" 
        action="#{bean.submit}" 
        disabled="#{not checkbox.value}" />
</h:form>
```

That's all. No additional JS code nor JSF bean properties or listener methods needed. Just a `submit()` action method.

The `binding` attribute will in this example put the [`UIComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html) reference of [`<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/selectBooleanCheckbox.html) in the Facelet scope under the variable name `checkbox`. The EL expression [`#{checkbox.value}`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIOutput.html#getValue%28%29) returns the `value` attribute of the component which represents in case of an [`UISelectBoolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UISelectBoolean.html) component already a `boolean`, ready for use in command component's `disabled` attribute.

Note: if you're facing an incorrect EL error at the line `disabled="#{not checkbox.value}"` in an older Eclipse version, then you'd need to configure it as follows: *Window > Preferences > Web > JavaServer Faces Tools > Validation > Type Coercion Problems > Unary operation boolean coercion problems* set it to *Warning* or *Ignore* instead of *Error*. This is not necessary anymore since Eclipse Mars.

#### See also:

- [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Comment: seriosly, any need for developers in Curaçao ? :) I'm in Netherlands right now and looking for a warmer place.

Comment: I'm working from home for a company in the Netherlands. Just look for a company which allows working from home ;)

Comment: this works perfect but I have a problem with button CSS, it does not "look" disabled when its disabled. I give style to button like this class="greyishBtn submitForm" any ideas?

Comment: This problem is unrelated to the initial question. It works for me on a blank playground project without any additional CSS. Perhaps you've overridden `input[disabled]` somewhere in a general stylesheet?

Answer (score 4):

You need to this by calling a valueChangeListener on ajax call so you can enable/disable button
Here is checkboxes and button

```
       <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="deactivate" title="select to deactivate" 
valueChangeListener="#{bean.myChangeListener}" onchange="submit()">

        <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{user.favNumber1}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Number1 - 1" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Number1 - 2" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Number1 - 3" />
            <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="dummyButton"/>
        </h:selectManyCheckbox>
    <h:commandButton id="dummyButton" value="OK" render="#{renderBean.myButton}">
```

You need create a render class with just one attribute whose value will be set in listener method i-e `bean#myChangeListener`

```
public class RenderBean{

    boolean myButton;
    public RendeBean(){

            myButton = true;

    }

    public void enableButton(){

          myButton = true;
    }

    public void disableButton(){

          myButton = false;
    }
}
```

And here is your `bean#myChangeListener`

```
public void myChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent e){
     RenderBean rb = (RenderBean) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("renderBean");
        if(e.getNewValue().toString().equals("1"))
                     rb.enableButton();
        else
                     rb.disableButton();
}
```