# Javascript: enable buttons on checkbox' check (both with ElementsByClass)

Tags: javascript, html, button, checkbox, getelementsbyclassname

I actually have a pretty simple question, but I've been trying for two days now and I just don't find an answer I need, or maybe I just don't understand it.

That is my problem:
I have two rows in a table:

1. row checkbox
2. row button

I want the button only be enabled, if the checkbox in the same row is enabled.
[Picture for better understanding](https://prnt.sc/k3rk2y)

```
<input type="checkbox" class="isaimed" name="attr_targeted_checkbox1">
<button type='roll' class="isroll" disabled="true">
```

I use classes and stumbled across `getElementsByClassName` and the fact, that you get an array/node of objects.
I tried something like this:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('isroll')
var keyselects = document.getElementsByClassName('isaimed');

for (var i = 0; i < keyselects.length; i++) {
    if (keyselects[i].checked == true) {
        buttons[i].disabled = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

and like 20 other codeparts and functions I found on the web, but it's not working. Maybe I have to assign the rows or something like that? 
Really, I am just utterly desperate and my mind is full of chunk right now.

Thank you very much for your help!

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/huf0zt45/)

Comment: You misspelled `'isaimed'` in the script. It is `'isamed'` in the markup. Does that help?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it was just a typo in fiddle I made. Thanks anyways! Fixed it :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable/Disable submit button if checkbox is checked/unchecked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021848/enable-disable-submit-button-if-checkbox-is-checked-unchecked)

Comment: That links answers use inline script and is not a good dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an `addEventListener` to your `input`'s to detect when they are clicked on.

Then, with `nextElementSibling`, you get the `button` and can toggle its state.

Stack snippet

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('isaimed');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {   

    if (this.checked) {
      this.nextElementSibling.removeAttribute("disabled");
      // or this.nextElementSibling.disabled = false;
      return;
    }

    this.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    // or this.nextElementSibling.disabled = true;

  })
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="isaimed" name="attr_targeted_checkbox1">
  <button type='roll' class="isroll" disabled="true">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="isaimed" name="attr_targeted_checkbox1">
  <button type='roll' class="isroll" disabled="true">Button</button>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="isaimed" name="attr_targeted_checkbox1">
  <button type='roll' class="isroll" disabled="true">Button</button>
</div>
```

---

Updated after question edit

In your fiddle the `input` and `button` aren't siblings, so here is an update that will work for the fiddle version of yours

```
if (this.checked) {
  this.parentElement.nextElementSibling.children[0].disabled = false;
  return;
}
this.parentElement.nextElementSibling.children[0].disabled = true;
```

Comment: Thank you for your super fast solution. It works like a charm in the snippet. Unfortunately not on my document. Could the table be an issue? I will add a fiddle, maybe its an issue on my side.

Comment: @Dysadia Add the fiddle here as a comment and I'll have a look

Comment: @Dysadia Ahh, the `input` and `button` in your code are not siblings, their parents are though, so here is an updated version of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/huf0zt45/2/

Comment: @Dysadia Also added that updated `if` statement to my answer