# is there any way to disable/enable upload button upon check/uncheck landed cost per line while user is editing the form?

Tags: netsuite

currently working on "to disable/enable upload button" (an added field) when user checked/unchecked checkbox. it's just for suites script or can do  in workflow?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtXOt.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable/Disable submit button if checkbox is checked/unchecked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021848/enable-disable-submit-button-if-checkbox-is-checked-unchecked)

Comment: i think no, can you elaborate your thoughts ?, thanks

Comment: you are right. I missed the tag there, sorry about that. Could you describe what you've tried so far?

Comment: i was trying to enable the added field (upload button) when checking the box of landed cost per line and disable it if it's not check or unchecked. my issue is, i can't manipulate it when i customize the form so i ask if it's working to doing workflow/suiteflow or suitescript.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with either a client suitescript or a workflow.  I believe there is a workflow action called After User Edit.  For client suitescript, you will create a function for the field change entry point.

Comment: i tried to do workflow but on the other hand i can't find "landed cost per line" (checkbox) as a field for Item Receipt record type when adding some condition

Comment: Field might not be supported in workflows, looks like client side script is your only option.

Comment: yup, i already using suitescript 1.0 later on prepared to use 2.0. question, do you have an idea to hide a field using 1.0?, and also when uploading a file using custom document field save to specific folder you created?