# Enable/Disable Submit Button with Javascript in combination with Primefaces and Twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, twitter-bootstrap, primefaces

I want to disable/enable a submit button if a checkbox is unchecked/checked, but the status of the button doesn't change.

I found a solution here:[How do i disable a submit button when checkbox is uncheck?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458531/how-do-i-disable-a-submit-button-when-checkbox-is-uncheck)

Checkbox:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="termsOfUseCheckbox" name="Sign Up" class="input-xlarge"/>
```

Submitbutton:

```
<p:commandButton type="submit" id="submitButton" action="#{genPlaceUserService.persist()}" value="Sign up" styleClass="btn btn-primary btn-large" disabled="true"></p:commandButton>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#termsOfUseCheckbox').click(function(){

    if($(this).attr('checked') == true){

        $('#submitButton').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('#submitButton').attr("disabled","true"); 
    }
});
```

I know that primefaces needs the state of disabled (disable=true), that should be done by:

```
$('#submitButton').attr("disabled","true");
```

grateful for any help,
kind regards!

Answer (score 1):

you could use this -> `$(this).is(':checked')` in place of `$(this).attr('checked')`, here's a jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/AfUGd/3/

edited the fiddle

Comment: thanks for your help! 
but the button still does not react on the status of the checkbox..

i know that xhtml needs disabled = "disbled", but i think primefaces needs disabled = "true". 

i tried both variants, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you need to do is not set disabled to true, but set disabled to disabled like this

```
$('#submitButton').attr("disabled","disabled");
```