# Click Checkbox to disabled button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to disabled the button to send the form until the checkbox is set and i want to solve it with a nice short jQuery Code. But there has to be a bug, nothing happens. Does anyone have an idea?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#terms').keyup(function(){
    if($('#terms').is(':checked')){
          $('#btn').removeAttr('disabled');
    }else{
        $('#btn').attr('disabled');
}})}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="terms" type="checkbox" value="" name="terms">
    <input id="btn"   name="register" type="button" value="Register" disabled/>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i disable a submit button when checkbox is uncheck?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458531/how-do-i-disable-a-submit-button-when-checkbox-is-uncheck)

Comment: Use the [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method _correctly_  instead of the `attr`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it's really simple:

```js
$('#terms').on("change", function() {
  $("#btn").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="terms" type="checkbox" value="" name="terms">
<input id="btn"   name="register" type="button" value="Register" disabled/>
```

where the `!this.checked` is the boolean value of the current checkbox state.
Naturally there's a jQuery way: `$(this).is(":not(:checked)")` but there's no need to, since you should get used to understand the `this` environment and the DOM Properties you have available using simple *vanilla* JS [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info).

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, you will get the "correct answer" soon. Need to wait a few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of attr:

e.g.

```
$('#btn').prop('disabled', true);
```

> Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without
>   changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the value
>   property of input elements, the disabled property of inputs and
>   buttons, or the checked property of a checkbox. The .prop() method
>   should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr()
>   method. The .val() method should be used for getting and setting
>   value.

Note: You are using `keyup` instead of the `change` event for a checkbox.

Note your example can be simplified to just pass a boolean expression for on/off:

```
$(function(){
    $('#terms').change(function(){
        $('#btn').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code is invalid. You're missing `);` and `$(this).is(':checked')` should be: `$(this).is(':not(:checked)')` or like `!$(this).is(':checked')`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks. "Invalid" is a bit strong for as typo, but corrected :)

Comment: strong, soft, call it as you like ;) the above will still hit hard since you're not closing properly your braces on the change function :) > therefore, yes, it's broken

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I do like leave some work for the OP (corrected) :) Be grateful you beat me by 10 seconds :)